# Customizing Outlook and Exchange to add new fields to meetings + querying from Exchange from custom app, is this possible?

Tags: outlook, vsto, exchange-server

Is it possible to customize the window used in Outlook to type in meetings (calendar tab) to add new fields to it ?
That data would be stored in Exchange, then queried by another app that would do something with it.

My problem is to see how I could affect the meeting edit dialog as it is now, to add my new fields.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is add some fields to the BOTTOM of the Appointment item inspector, then you can do that very easily with VSTO.  It's called a custom outlook form region.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157865.aspx

However, if you want to change elements in the base inspector form itself then that's much more difficult, and involves significantly more work. I don't have a complete answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this pretty easily with custom forms.

Just derive from the "ipm.appointment" appointment form and add you fields and logic to validate and save those fields as user properties on the meeting item
You can then attach to exchange using RDO or OOM to call back the properties off the meeting items.

you can then publish the form to you whole organisation if you want and over righ the default with soem reg key changes.

or

you can do as above and create yourself an addin using vsto.